# c++ print vowels of a GIVEN txt file in a directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I want to query the user for the name of a text file, read that file and count and display the total number of vowels in the file.

I do not have any problems in finding the number of vowels, but I just don't know how to read that specific text file.

I was thinking at something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    string fileName;
    char c;
    int nNum = 0;


    cout << "Enter the file name: ";
    getline(cin, fileName);

    // Open the file
    inputFile.open(fileName.c_str());

    // Check for successful opening
    if(inputFile.fail())
    {
       cerr << "Error Opening File" << endl;
       return(1);
    }
    while(!inputFile.eof())
    {
        inputFile.get(c);
        if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' ||  c == 'o' ||  c == 'i' || c == 'u')
            nNum++;
    }
    inputFile.close();
    cout << nNum;
    return 0;
}
```

I get `Error opening file` when I enter: test.txt ( it is located on my Desktop). What am I doing wrong ?

---

UPDATE: Changed while loop to avoid addition of a character:

```
 while(inputFile.get(c))
    {
        if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' ||  c == 'o' ||  c == 'i' || c == 'u')
            nNum++;
    }
```

Still looking for a solution that will allow me to enter just the name of the file (without the path), wherever it is, so that I can read from it.

Comment: I expect the current working directory of your application is not the desktop (so the file will not be in the place your application will look) so you will have to enter the full path which is not exactly easy for the desktop. In Visual Studio the default is the folder containing the .sln file. I expect that you did not change the path in the debug settings for your project.

Comment: I figured that just now when I entered the full path. Is there a way to neglect this and enter just the name of the file ?

Comment: You can just enter the file name only if the file is in the current working directory of the application you are running.

Comment: Here is how you get the current working directory of your application in windows: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Note that thanks to the (broken, as usual) use of `while (!inputFile.eof())`, the result you get can/will be wrong (if the last character it reads is a vowel, you'll get a result that's one greater than it should be).

Comment: Thanks for the head-ups, @Jerry. How to avoid this ?

Comment: You normally want to attempt a read and check the result, as in: `while (inputFile.get(c))` (in your case) or `while (inputFile >> somevar)`, `while (std::getline(inputFile, my_line))`, etc.

Comment: Thank you. Updated. Still looking for a solution if there's any.

Comment: @Alexander - If you don't wish to allow a file from any location to be read, you should show a msg that says only the desktop will be checked for files with the entered name. You then need to follow drescherjm's link in order to get the path of the desktop 4 the logged-in user. After doing this, you'll need to concatenate this string and the the one entered by the user. I don't remember if you'll need to add either '/' or '\\' between the two strings, as I dont recall if the folder returned has a forward slash/double back-slash as the last character, or if it's just an alphanumeric character.

Comment: Another question: will this code run on a Mac OS C++ compiler ? I don't have the chance to test it right now. @enhzflep

Comment: @Alexander - seems like it should be fine. In fact, if the convention for an alias to the user's home folder is the same in MacOS as it is in Linux, it will be even easier than the Windows solution, since you don't need to query the system for the name of the user's folder - you can simply use ~/Desktop or whatever is the appropriate string. In Linux, the `~/` folder is an alias to the current user's home folder and `~/Desktop` maps to the desktop of whichever user is logged-in. Much easier than `/home/*userNameHere*/Desktop` - a rather neat feature I've always enjoyed in *nix.